# How can I write this with less redundancy/copy-paste?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I usually don't write my Python code in the best way since I'm relatively new to it, someone requested that I make changes to a Django app since the code doesn't look so nice.

Here's what it looks like:

```
@login_required
def submission_set_rank(request):   

    r1_obj_id = request.GET.get('rank1','')
    r2_obj_id = request.GET.get('rank2','')
    r3_obj_id = request.GET.get('rank3','')
    r4_obj_id = request.GET.get('rank4','')
    r5_obj_id = request.GET.get('rank5','')

    #rate the first BallotStats object
    ballot_1 = BallotStats.objects.get(object_id=r1_obj_id)
    ballot_2 = BallotStats.objects.get(object_id=r2_obj_id)
    ballot_3 = BallotStats.objects.get(object_id=r3_obj_id)
    ballot_4 = BallotStats.objects.get(object_id=r4_obj_id)
    ballot_5 = BallotStats.objects.get(object_id=r5_obj_id)

    ballot_1.score += 5
    ballot_2.score += 4
    ballot_3.score += 3
    ballot_4.score += 2
    ballot_5.score += 1

    ballot_1.save()
    ballot_2.save()
    ballot_3.save()
    ballot_4.save()
    ballot_5.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/submissions/results/film/')
```

As it turns out I realized that I've always been writing my Python code this way, is there a way to make it look better instead of taking up 21+ lines of code?

Comment: loops loops loops loops :) a little `for ... in ...` wouldn't hurt a bit

Comment: @Carsten don't agree - this is not only about the code style and the size and beauty of it. It is also about performance. Plus, it is really django specific.

Comment: This should be a `Form` with `ModelChoiceField`s and a `save()` method overridden.

Comment: @alecxe okay. Especially with the additional info in your answer, this really _is_ a better fit for SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The biggest problem is not the style of the code - it is that you are making 10 queries: 5 for getting the objects and 5 for updating them.

Filter out objects using [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) at once:

```
@login_required
def submission_set_rank(request):   
    keys = {'rank1': 5, 'rank2': 4, 'rank3': 3, 'rank4': 2, 'rank5': 1}
    ranks = [request.GET.get(key,'') for key in keys]
    for ballot in BallotStats.objects.filter(object_id__in=ranks):
        ballot.score += keys[ballot.object_id]
        ballot.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/submissions/results/film/')
```

This will make 6 queries at most: 1 for getting the objects and 5 for updating them.

Also, you can "mark" the view with the [`commit_manually`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually) decorator ([`commit_on_success`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_on_success) would also work for you). It should [speed up things significantly](http://voorloopnul.com/blog/doing-bulk-update-and-bulk-create-with-django-orm/):

```
@login_required
@transaction.commit_manually
def submission_set_rank(request):   
    keys = {'rank1': 5, 'rank2': 4, 'rank3': 3, 'rank4': 2, 'rank5': 1}
    ranks = [request.GET.get(key,'') for key in keys]
    for ballot in BallotStats.objects.filter(object_id__in=ranks):
        ballot.score += keys[ballot.object_id]
        ballot.save()
    transaction.commit()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/submissions/results/film/')
```

And I have the strong feeling that you can do this in even a single update query. For example, by using  [`connection.cursor()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) directly with the help of `executemany()`:

```
@login_required
def submission_set_rank(request):   
    keys = {'rank1': 5, 'rank2': 4, 'rank3': 3, 'rank4': 2, 'rank5': 1}
    ranks = [{'score': request.GET.get(key,''), 'id': key} for key in keys]

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.executemany("""
        UPDATE
            ballot_stats
        SET
            score = score + %(score)s
        WHERE
            object_id = %(id)s
    """, ranks)

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/submissions/results/film/')
```

Make sure the field and table names are correct.

Comment: Why show a `@transaction.commit_manually` example and not an example using the much simpler built-in [`update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update), which the [article](http://voorloopnul.com/blog/doing-bulk-update-and-bulk-create-with-django-orm/) you link to actually finds to be faster? 5 `.filter().update()` calls will make exactly 5 queries.

Comment: @pcoronel because it is not a simple update. Here different values are set for the field depending on the `object_id` value. Let me know if you can write it down using `update()`. Thanks.

Comment: Using [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions) expressions: `BallotStats.objects.filter(object_id=request.GET.get('rank1','')).update(score=F('score') + 5)`, 5 of those will take care of it and doesn't need dict mappings

Comment: @pcoronel okay, thanks. But I meant a single `update()`. Your solution would make 5 database hits. Though, yes, it is an option too.

Answer (score 6):

In your case, a little bit of looping wouldn't hurt at all. In fact, as a general rule, whenever you have to repeat something more than twice, try to make it a loop.

```
n = 5
for i in range(1, n+1):
    obj_id = request.GET('rank' + str(i), '')
    ballot = BallotStats.objects.get(object_id=obj_id)
    ballot.score += n - i + 1
    ballot.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about saving lines of code, you can combine the 4 lines into one line, by replacing your `.save()` with a [`.update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) and using an [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions) expression to take care of the `+=`. Also, as discussed by @alecxe, this will cut your queries in half. It'd look like this:

```
@login_required
def submission_set_rank(request):
    BallotStats.objects.filter(object_id=request.GET.get('rank1','')).update(score=‌​F('score') + 5)
    BallotStats.objects.filter(object_id=request.GET.get('rank2','')).update(score=‌​F('score') + 4)
    BallotStats.objects.filter(object_id=request.GET.get('rank3','')).update(score=‌​F('score') + 3)
    BallotStats.objects.filter(object_id=request.GET.get('rank4','')).update(score=‌​F('score') + 2)
    BallotStats.objects.filter(object_id=request.GET.get('rank5','')).update(score=‌​F('score') + 1)

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/submissions/results/film/')
```